# Update text in a figure Using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text, matlab-figure

I want to update the text in a figure using MATLAB .For example,In figure i write text "Initial value" in one coordinate. After pause ,i want to show in same coordinate  "Final value" text instead of "initial value".How can i update "initial value" text to "Final Value" text. There is any command which update the text in MATLAB figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the [graphics handle object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html#outputarg_t) returned by `text`, and use that to update the [`String` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html#property_string) of the object which will change the displayed text.

```
txt = text(0.5, 0.5, 'Initial Value');
pause(1);
set(txt, 'String', 'Final Value')
```

This same procedure can be used to update [*any* graphics object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/understanding-handle-graphics-objects.html) that you display in MATLAB. The properties and values will change between object types but the general idea remains the same.

Comment: @Tina Yes because you ran the commands one after another. I have added a pause into the example. The idea is that you call the first line when you *create* the object and the second line when you want to update it (theoretically after some calculations).